# Symfony Bundle: how to avoid using __DIR__ to build the path to Doctrine mappings

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I'm finding myself dealing with the same problem in multiple bundles I've wrote.

The problem is that in my `BundleNameBundle` class I have to create the path to then load the mappings of Doctrine.

To do this I do something like:

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    parent::build($container);

    $modelDir = realpath(__DIR__ . '/Resources/config/doctrine/mappings');
    $mappings = [
        $modelDir => 'SerendipityHQ\Bundle\QueuesBundle\Model',
    ];

    $ormCompilerClass = DoctrineOrmMappingsPass::class;
    if (class_exists($ormCompilerClass)) {
        $container->addCompilerPass(
            $this->getYamlMappingDriver($mappings)
        );
    }

    $container->addCompilerPass(new DaemonDependenciesPass());
}
```

Complete code [here](https://github.com/Aerendir/bundle-queues/blob/master/QueuesBundle.php).

As you can see I use `__DIR__` to get the path to the folder where the mappings are.

Now, Sensio Insights is alerting me that "[Absolute path constants **DIR** and **FILE** should not be used](https://insight.sensiolabs.com/projects/2a1bcd2f-f241-4969-96e4-10ead299d57b/analyses/13#rule-22-014)".

Ok, but how can I solve this problem? Is there some alternative way to build the path to the mappings?

Comment: @Gordon, this is not a duplicate as the solution provided in the question you linked is not applicable to my case.

Using `$container->get('kernel')->locateResource('@QueuesBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/mappings')` is not possible as it triggers the error "You have requested a non-existent service "kernel".". The solution refers to the resource location in Controller, while I'm in the initialization file of the bundle: in this context the `kernel` is not already available. Please, remove the duplication flag.

Comment: Ok, I'll still link this here for reference though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331370/why-absolute-path-constants-dir-and-file-should-not-be-used-in-symfony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$this->path`. It returns the same result as `__DIR__`

Comment: I've used `$this->getPath()` I prefere to use getters! Thank you for the answer!